# Android EditText not expanding when hitting enter

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I have a `EditText` look like this in my layout xml and it's not expanding when the user hit enter

```
<EditText 
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/edSearch"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:hint="City..."
        />
```

but when i changed `android:layout_height="40dp"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` the the edittext is able to expand as the user hit enter.

how I can keep my `EditText` expanding while keeping this line `android:layout_height="40dp"`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<EditText 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="Top"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/edSearch"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:hint="City..."
        />
```

Hope this will work

Comment: You should add some explanation to your answers (in the future too!) to avoid them being flagged for deletion!

Comment: sir, i guess youre not reading my question. i can make my edittext expanding when the user hit enter when i use wrap_content but cant achive it with fixed initial height 40dp...

Comment: How can you do that if you fix your view height, you have change it to wrap_content and set minHeight to 40 dp then it will work

Answer (score 1):

I'm using following code and it's working great. to set minimum height instead of setting layout_height to 40dp set it wrap_content and set attribute of minLines to achieve this as show below in code example

```
  <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:minLines="4"
        android:maxLines="10"
         />
```

Comment: sir, this is absolutely working but what i want is to set the height to fixed 40 dp not wrap_content

Comment: what i understood from your question and this comment you want edittext to be shown with minimum height of 40dp either it is empty or filled and when it get filled with text having height more than 40dp you want it to expand itself accordingly. for auto expanding you have to set layout_height="wrap_content" and to set a minimum height use what you are already using i.e  minHeight="40dp" now it'll have 40dp height by default and will expand when filled with text.

Comment: to view result change minHeight to 80dp or 100dp as 40dp is only height equal to a single line

Comment: unfortunately sir, the initial size still seem wrap_content not 40dp
ive used exactly like your answer and keeping minHeight as 40dp

Comment: just try this change minHeight to 140dp and then you'll see the change as actually 40dp is just height of a single line that's is why you mis-understanding it with wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

Set property `android:multiline="true"`.
hope this will help you.

Comment: sir, android:multiline="true" error unknown attribute

Comment: Add this two property: android:inputType="textMultiLine"      android:singleLine="false" Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Set  `android:multiline="true"` along with  `android:gravity="left|top"`